# How do I spawn custom mobs?

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to spawn one entity from my class which customizes `EntityZombie`.

```
World bukkit; // ...
CraftWorld craft = (CraftWorld)bukkit;
net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.World world = craft.getHandle();
Boss boss = new Boss(world);
Location spawn; // ...
boss.setLocation(spawn.getX(), spawn.getY(), spawn.getZ(), spawn.getYaw(), spawn.getPitch());
world.addEntity(boss);
```

---

```
public class Boss extends EntityZombie {
    public Boss(World world) {
        super(world);
    }
    // Empty right now, nothing more than the normal zombie
}
```

The output is:

- If I run the code above by staying away, when I come back I see nothing.
- If I run it by being close, the client crashes.

Nothing relevant in console, here's the full crash report.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Who set us up the TNT?

Time: 06/03/15 14.57
Description: Ticking screen

java.lang.NullPointerException: Ticking screen
    at bjb.a(SourceFile:514)
    at fz.a(SourceFile:97)
    at fz.a(SourceFile:15)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:174)
    at bcx.e(SourceFile:78)
    at bao.p(SourceFile:1343)
    at bao.ak(SourceFile:774)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:728)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at bjb.a(SourceFile:514)
    at fz.a(SourceFile:97)
    at fz.a(SourceFile:15)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:174)
    at bcx.e(SourceFile:78)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 1 total; [bjk['System_'/1, l='MpServer', x=-518,50, y=5,62, z=754,50]]
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 10, 10
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 01 - flat, ver 0. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (-519,4,756), Chunk: (at 9,0,4 in -33,47; contains blocks -528,0,752 to -513,255,767), Region: (-2,1; contains chunks -64,32 to -33,63, blocks -1024,0,512 to -513,255,1023)
    Level time: 45 game time, 45 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 1 total; [bjk['System_'/1, l='MpServer', x=-518,50, y=5,62, z=754,50]]
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: Spigot
    Server type: Non-integrated multiplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at bjf.a(SourceFile:289)
    at bao.b(SourceFile:1972)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:737)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 136194320 bytes (129 MB) / 186380288 bytes (177 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.7.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: GeForce GT 440/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.4.0, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.

    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: On (2)
```

Perhaps, do I need to register any custom mob for each biome first? If yes, how?

Comment: When your client crashes, what's your log? Also, is there anything in console?

Comment: @Joiner What's in your boss class?

Comment: repost as comment: Something with your entity renderer is wrong - "If I run it by being close, my client crashes." Have you added a custom entity renderer to the registry?

If you can, try to find out what caused the NullPointerException at bjb.a(SourceFile:514). You might get a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You could download RemoteEntities Api from: 
[HERE](http://bukkit.org/threads/lib-1-7-remote-entities-next-generation-npc-library-no-support.110304/)

You can download other custom mob api if you want but I recommend you using it.

Comment: Library is outdated and this should be a comment.